# Programmatically change mouse cursor on Flutter

Tags: flutter

I know we can change mouse cursor using widgets (like `MouseRegion` or `InkWell.mouseCursor`), but how can you change it programmatically ?

My use case : I want to set the cursor to `SystemMouseCursors.click` when it's hovering (easy behaviour), and to `SystemMouseCursors.move` when it start to be dragged (that's when I need to do it programmatically).

Comment: I just spent a good hour on this, and I don't think there's a way without plugins. When you mouse down the current cursor is frozen in place, and there doesn't seem to be any getting around this behavior.